# Enable Split View In Lightning

Tags: lightning, view, split

My lightning org does not have Split View enabled. 
I am trying to find where it can be enabled from but with no success.
What I observed is some of my Apps has it enabled while the others don't.
From where can I enable the split view ?

Comment: Are you able to see the option in settings of a list view? [Link](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_general_lightning_console_split_view.htm)

Comment: Do you have salesforce console?   It looks like the split view is only available in salesforce console apps.

Comment: @JRiffe I see the split view in one of the apps of my org, but not in all of them. How do I check if it is a Salesforce console ?

Comment: @manjit_singh I checked the link you shared. I can see only Table and Kanban under display as. However in one of the apps in my org I can see Split view under Kanban as well. But I need to activate it in other apps

Comment: As @JRiffe said - the split view comes with salesforce console, other views don't have the console capabilities. If on your apps you can see `Sales Console` or `Service Console` - these apps would open a split view, each for each own cloud